# linux+apache2.2+wsgi+python got extra content when uploading file

Tags: python, linux, wsgi

I setup linux+apache2.2.+wsgi+python environment to test file uploading.
There are totally 2 pages, one is to let user select the file to be uploaded; another is to handle file upload.

Expected result:
a file uploaded with correct file content.

Actual result:
a file is uploaded, but content is original file content plus part of http header and start/end line. like:

```
-----------------------------40976349392994148594600211
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="filename"; filename="configure.scan"
Content-Type: application/octet-stream
[original file content]
-----------------------------40976349392994148594600211
```

Anybody there can give my answer? I will deeply appreciate your help.

**the first page code**:

```
output= '<html><head>' +\  
        '<br>' + \  
        '</head><body>' + \  
        '<form name="form1" action=“/dynamic/postuploadfile.py” enctype="multipart/form-data" method=“post”>' +\  
        'File: <input type="file" name="test" size=50><br />' +\  
        '<input type=“submit” value="upload"/>' +\  
        '</form></body></html>'  

def application(environ, start_response):  
    status = '200 OK'  
    response_headers = [('Content-type', 'text/html'),  
                        ('Content-Length', str(len(output)))]  
    start_response(status, response_headers)  
    return [output]
```

**The second page code:**

```
import os  

def upload(environ):    

    # A nested FieldStorage instance holds the file  
    #fileitem = req.form['file']  
    data = environ['wsgi.input'].read(int(environ.get('CONTENT_LENGTH','0')))  

    message = ''  
    open('uploaded', 'wb').write(data)  
    message = 'The file was uploaded successfully'  

    return ( '<html><body>' + message + '</body><html>' )  

def application(environ, start_response):  
    status = '200 OK'  
    output = upload( environ )  
    response_headers = [('Content-type', 'text/html'),  
                        ('Content-Length', str(len(output)))]  
    start_response(status, response_headers)  
    return [output]
```

Answer (score 2):

Yes. This is the *proper* behavior. By using the **mime encapsulation**, more than one file can be uploaded. How would you do this otherwise?

Have a look at the `cgi.FieldStorage` class of python, which has various functionality for handling **multipart** mime types as used for CGI requests.

**Do not handle this naively**. There are situations where the file contents will need to be encoded or decoded. The most obvious case is that when the uploaded text file itself contains the separator string (`-----------------------------40976349392994148594600211`
 in your example), it needs to be encoded somehow.

You can also try the WSGI python toolkit werkzeug, see  http://werkzeug.pocoo.org/docs/http/#module-werkzeug.formparser

Comment: thanks for your answer. If in this case, how to figure out where is real content of the file. and before uploading file, I have no idea what is separator string, like -----------------------------40976349392994148594600211, am I right. If before uploading file, do encoding it, this problem will not be there.

Comment: This is exactly why you should use the *existing parsers* for getting the actual file from the *multipart* upload.

Comment: What's the existing parsers you suggest to get the actual file? Is wsgi+python so complicated to handle file upload, while PHP is so simple:
      move_uploaded_file($_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"],
      "upload/" . $_FILES["file"]["name"]);

Comment: Did you try the `email` package I mentioned above. I believe it can parse MIME multipart contents.

Comment: Yes, I have try email module in following way, but still got same result.

msg = email.message_from_string( data )
for part in msg.walk():
    ctype = part.get_content_type()
    data1 = part.get_payload(decode=True)
Above loop actually do only once, and data1 is same as data. No idea where is wrong. Can you help me with this.

Comment: Try the `werkzeug` python wsgi library. http://werkzeug.pocoo.org/docs/http/#module-werkzeug.formparser

Comment: Or use the cgi.FieldStorage class from the standard library which is the more traditional way of handling form posts. One would not usually use the email module directly for web stuff.

Comment: Thanks Anony-Mousse and Graham Dumleton, I appreciate your help. I already tried FieldStorage, and wekzeug for me is too heavy/complicated, so I do it by myself. I write a class to parse environ['wsgi.input']. in the class, I firstly call re.search()( regular expression lib) to get separator, then use str.split get each form content, lastly get file name and file content.

Comment: This sounds like a **very bad idea** to me. Do you handle all encodings, too? How about escaping, newline handling and such? You are **guessing** at a protocol that is well-defined. Make sure to fully implement RFC2388 & related standards to get support for *all* browsers. http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc2388.txt

Comment: In my code, escaping and new line are taken into account. So far no probllem it is and working nicely. 
Yeah, I agree wtih you it is not good idea to do it in this way in commercial product, but for me, it is good. As now I am study python and python web development. So I try do most of thing by myself not depend on 3rd library.
Thanks for your reminder very much, let me know that there is and what is related document for MIME.